# What is SESSION in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count the number of MySQL queries made for page generation by PHP script. I use the following query:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS WHERE Variable_name LIKE  'Questions';
```

But it gives me some huge number (millions). I have searched MySQL docs and man pages, but haven't found a definition what exactly "session" means.

It seems that the session is not the same as current connection.

I will be much obliged if anyone explains what a session is, when it starts and when ends.

Comment: Here is your answer:- http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54337/difference-between-show-status-and-show-global-status-in-mysql
Check the correct answer and just read it carefully

Comment: I found a way to determine the number of queries. I run the above query at the beginning of the script and at the end and calculate the balance between values. However, my main question remains unanswered. I really want to understand what a session is in MySQL.

Comment: that definition and understanding given in the link that i gave you

Comment: I saw the answer before asking my question. It seems that (some versions of) php keep the connection alive permanently, that is why I get huge numbers from SHOW SESSION STATUS query. I ran tests on PHP 5.2 (php-cgi) and the number of "Questions" isn't reset from script to script. While on PHP 5.6 ran as php-fpm the counter is reset.

Comment: I am not too sure but If you create a connection in php and if  you not explicitly close it, that will remain

Comment: maybe useful? [LOCAL, SESSION, AND GLOBAL VARIABLES IN MYSQL](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0201__Procedure-Function/LOCALSESSIONANDGLOBALVARIABLESINMYSQL.htm). Explains what a `session` is considered to be.

Comment: This is the most useful link! Thank you! I wish I could put a green tick next to it :)

Comment: `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()` will tell you if you're reusing connections or not.  Connection == session, and these are the `ID` numbers from `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-status.html):

> With a `SESSION` modifier, the statement displays the status variable values for the current connection. If a variable has no session value, the global value is displayed.

I think the issue is that, if you run `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Questions';` when you first create a database connection, no queries have yet been executed, so `GLOBAL` data is shown. When you connect via a command-line `mysql` client, the client executes a couple of queries on startup, so the session has this variable set. Try running a query before you `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Questions'`.

Comment: No this is definitely not GLOBAL data, because when I count the difference between "Questions" at the start and at the end of the script it remains the same when I reload the target webpage. I tried to run "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS" queries and the difference changes each time (because other users view the site at the same time). I think the most correct answer is that PHP keeps the connection alive. However, then another question appears: does PHP open and retain mysql session per each php session? It seems, yes.

Comment: That will probably depend on things like connection pooling and persistence. Can you post your PHP code where you're calling it in your question, and show how you're connecting to MySQL?

Comment: I noticed that different versions of PHP behave differently, so I don't think it's woth seeing my code, because it is php's version dependent.